# Query works in GraphIQL, but not in Relay Classic

Tags: react-native, graphql, relayjs, relay, graphiql

I am trying to make a query to get a list of participants. In GraphiQL, this works. However, on the front end with React-Native/RelayClassic, the query only returns one participants

In GraphiQL:

```
query getJobInfo ($sessionToken: String!, $jobId: String!) {
  viewer(sessionToken: $sessionToken){
    job(jobId: $jobId){
      jobId
      title
      participants(first: 1000) {
        edges {
          node {
           userId
           firstName
           lastName
           profilePic
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where edges returns many participants

In RelayClassic:

```
const RelayCompletionPeople = 
  Relay.createContainer(UnconnectedCompletionPeople, {
    initialVariables: {
      jobId: "abcd123",
    },
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Viewer {
          job(jobId: $jobId) {
            jobId
            title
            participants (first: 1000) {
              edges {
                node {
                  userId
                  firstName
                  lastName
                  profilePic
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
    }
  });
```

where edges returns only one participant

What it is that is causing this to happen?

Are there other places in my code that I need to look in order to return a list?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for quite awhile.

**Update**:

I found the issue. There was a parent relay container that conflicted with the number of participants that could reach the completionPeople container.

Comment: Your query looks to be correct. Have you updated your schema? Can you provide the result of ```console.log(this.props.viewer)```?

Comment: this.props.viewer = { job: “abcd123”, {
     participants: 
      { edges:
        [ node: 
        { 
        firstName: “some name”,
        lastName: “some name”,
        profilePIc: “asdfsadf.jpg”,
        userID: “asdfasdfaf”
        }
       ]
      }
     }
    }

I have not updated the schema

Comment: the edges array's length is only one. It should be greater than one. The database also shows that their is more than one participant.